# Array to Hash with conditional logic in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.1

`ruby 2.1.1`

Is there a way to do the logic in this piece of code in one line or a more concise manner?

```
user = User.new
h = Hash.new
attrs = [:name, :foo, :bar]
attrs.each do |a|
    h[a] = user[a] if user.has_attribute? a
end
return h
```

Comment: From a matter of style, `Hash.new` with no options is almost always written as simply `{ }`. It's also unnecessary to use `return r` when `r` at the end of the method has exactly the same effect. The only place `return` is normally used is to break out of a method early.

Comment: Are you using Rails ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes, I am using `Rails 4.1.1`

Comment: tag your question also then...

Comment: @ArupRakshit k, tagged, at first I thought ruby would have a complete solution to this issue.  Didn't think rails would have such a better alternative. Now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Rails and User is an ActiveRecord model (which it looks like given your use of `has_attribute?`) then this will do the same thing:

```
user = User.new
...
return user.attributes.slice("name", "foo", "bar")
```

Or, if you really want symbols:

```
return user.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:name, :foo, :bar)
```

Comment: Your answer is compact one liner.. But just remove *return*, It is not need.

Comment: I left the `return` there to make it clear to the asker that this is the final result, in place of what he was returning before. Nothing wrong with a `return` if it adds clarity. :)

Comment: I concede… I just like my returns :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on Rails. If so,then -

```
attrs = [:name, :foo, :bar]
# the result hash will be returned, if last line of the method.
user.attributes.extract!(*attrs)
```

Look these methods [`extract!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-extract-21) and [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes).

Example :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Rails/app> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
2.0.0-p451 :001 > h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
2.0.0-p451 :002 > h.extract!(:a ,:b ,:x)
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
2.0.0-p451 :003 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are correct in Rails scope, I'l just add generic solution:

```ruby
# assuming user[a] returns nil, if user have no a attribute
[:name, :foo, :bar].
  map{|a| [attr, user[a]]}.
  reject{|k, v| v.nil?}.
  to_h

# assuming user[a] can raise if not user.has_attribute?(a)
[:name, :foo, :bar].
   map{|a| [attr, user.has_attribute?(a) && user[a]]}.
   reject{|k, v| !v}.
   to_h
```

I've formatted them as NOT one-liners, but they are still one-statements :)

Basically, the trick is "invent the right method chain to convert one sequence to other", and requires to know all Enumerable sequence-transforming methods (map/select/reduce/reject/...), as well as a method to transform array of key-value pairs into hash (`#to_h` is standard in Ruby 2.1.1)